# How to find listener in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, containers

Now I am reading servlet action listener. My question is how container know which class is listener?

Answer (score 1):

listeners are defined in the web.xml file descriptor. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm) for more information. Notably:

> Create an event listener class by implementing the appropriate
>   interface or interfaces of the javax.servlet package or
>   javax.servlet.http package.
>
> Event listeners are declared in the application web.xml deployment
>   descriptor through  elements under the top-level 
>   element. Each listener has its own  element, with a
>    subelement specifying the class name. Within each
>   event category, event listeners should be specified in the order in
>   which you would like them to be invoked when the application runs.

Answer (score 0):

in web.xml you can find it

```
<listener>
        <listener-class></listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

We specify in DD

Ex:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>javax.servlet.ServletContextListene</listener-class>
</listener>
```